# Manipulate value of ActiveRecord request in Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, chartkick

I like to use [chartkick](http://chartkick.com/) to visualize some data. I have a Purchase model with many purchases in it.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :price, :product, :purchase_type
  def invert_price
    self.price.abs
  end
end
```

A standard chart would look like:

```
<%= bar_chart Purchase.group(:category).sum(:price) %>
```

But my :price records are negativ. I just need a solution how I get to a inverted price (-price) or the absolute value of price (price.abs).
Trying to create a method in the Purchase model doesn't work, because it can't get resolved in a SQL query.

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category, :price, :product, :purchase_type

  def invert_price
    self.price.abs
  end

  def invert_price
    self.price.abs
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'invert_price' in 'field list
```

Writing a own SQL query could give back the right result, but chartkick was empty after it.

```
<%= bar_chart Purchase.select("ABS(SUM(`candystore_purchases`.`price`)) AS sum_price, category AS category").group(:category) %>
```

Any ideas, how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= bar_chart Purchase.group(:category).sum("ABS(price)") %>
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(ABS(price)) AS sum_abs_price, category AS category FROM 'purchases' GROUP BY category` is the produced sql query, exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!